# Breeze Navigation Array Members are DependentObservables in Knockout?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze

I am using the clicktoedit binding handler that RP Niemeyer posted long ago.  It works great:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.hidden = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.visible.update(element, function() { return     !ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()); });
    }        
};

ko.bindingHandlers.clickToEdit = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var observable = valueAccessor(),
            link = document.createElement("a"),
            input = document.createElement("input");

        element.appendChild(link);
        element.appendChild(input);

        observable.editing = ko.observable(false);

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(link, {
            text: observable,
            hidden: observable.editing,
            click: observable.editing.bind(null, true)
        });

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(input, {
            value: observable,
            visible: observable.editing,
            hasfocus: observable.editing,
            event: {
                keyup: function(data, event) {
                //if user hits enter, set editing to false, which makes field lose focus
                    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                       observable.editing(false);
                       return false;
                    }
                //if user hits escape, push the current observable value back to the field, then set editing to false
                    else if (event.keyCode === 27) {
                       observable.valueHasMutated();
                       observable.editing(false);
                       return false;
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

The problem I have is that it the escape key does NOT work with elements from arrays provided by BreezeJS.  Apparently these are dependentObservables and do not have the valueHasMutated method.  I'm generally confused about 
a) how could I modify this to work for Breeze dependent observables? and
b) why are they dependent observables?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Breeze.js is already taking care of the 'undo' for your entities so the binding handler you have is a bit unnecessary.  Without knowing exactly how you are using it and what other context's might be affected you could always check to see if it is a Breeze entity first and fallback to the current implementation if not -

```
keyup: function(data, event) {
//if user hits enter, set editing to false, which makes field lose focus
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
       observable.editing(false);
       return false;
    }
//if user hits escape, push the current observable value back to the field, then set editing to false
    else if (event.keyCode === 27) {
       if (observable.entityAspect) {
           observable.entityAspect.cancelChanges();
           observable.editing(false);
           return false;
       } else {
           observable.valueHasMutated();
           observable.editing(false);
           return false;
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, PW Kad.  That certainly seems logical.  But my DependentObservables don't seem to have the entityAspect property.  I've only had time for a quick test of this approach, so I haven't delved down into the details.  I'll let you know when I get a chance to find out more.